# Summation of two products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Hey I'm a bit rusty on this stuff but I would like to figure out how would I go about solving this? 
$$\sum_{t=1}^{n-k+1} t \cdot \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^t + \frac{nk}{n+1}$$

Comment: Perhaps first do $\sum_{t=1}^K t r^t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$S = \sum_{t=1}^{n-k+1} t \cdot \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^t$$, then $$\sum_{t=1}^{n-k+1} lnS = \sum_{t=1}^{n-k+1} ln(t \cdot \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^t) = \sum_{t=1}^{n-k+1} ln(t) +ln\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \sum_{t=1}^{n-k+1}t$$ = $$ln(\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2*(n+1)^(\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2}})$$
Hence, $$S = \frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2*(n+1)^(\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2}}$$

Therefore in total,  $$\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2*(n+1)^(\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2}} + \frac{nk}{n+1}$$